# Facebook like button comment box not working with flickr

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, flickr

I have a js fiddle that demonstrates the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/RLQUR/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.flickr.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

The code in the fiddle is directly from the facebook like button generator.

If you change the url to something like "http://www.google.com" it works just as it should. However, when using a flickr url and trying to click "Post to Facebook" it makes an AJAX request and returns with a status of 200 OK but does not post the comment to the profile or close the popup.

I believe this is likely a bug with the facebook like button, however I am unable to create a bug on the developer page for an unknown reason. I do not see a "Create" button on the page.

Any help is appreciated.